# jquery mobile bind/live tap

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to bind a tap event to no avail:

```
$('label[for=p_divisionR]').bind('tap', function(){
    $('#propertyTypeDivision').parent().show();
    $("#propertyType").parent().hide(); 
    $("#propertyTypeDivisionRL").parent().hide(); 
    hideBedrooms();
});
```

I have tried with `.live('tap', fn)` as well which doesn't work. However when on a desktop, using `.live('click', fn)` works fine.

Why would the `click` event work but not tap? It's being tested on an iPad using jQuery mobile rc1.

See:

http://m.bentons.propertylogic.net/

Comment: Hmm looks correct to me, maybe pass the event to the function and see if it's being called: bind('tap', function(event, ui). Also any errors?

Comment: No errors unfortunately, and passing the event didnt work! :( see updated q for link

Comment: what about trying .live('vclick', fn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vclick` There were issues with `tap` back in the beta days and their developers recommended people use `vclick`. `vclick` will work on both mobile and desktop. Tap will sometimes trigger multiple events.

```
$('#p_divisionR').live('change', function(){
    $('#propertyTypeDivision').parent().show();
    $("#propertyType").parent().hide(); 
    $("#propertyTypeDivisionRL").parent().hide(); 
    hideBedrooms();
});
```

EDIT: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jostster/UHX5k/1/
Forgot you were using radio buttons. For those you should use `change` instead of `vclick`

Comment: I know this is not a solution, but this **may** have been fixed in the final release. I guess it's worth a try: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/11/16/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-0/

Comment: @Smamatti When I spoke to the developer he gave the impression that it would never be fixed as tap was not supposed to used as a clicking event but more of a very quick tap event. He stated he wasn't sure of a way to fix it and didn't really plan on it since tap wasn't to be used in that manner.

Comment: I've upgraded to jQuery mobile 1.0 and changed my `click` events to `vclick` events but to no avail. I have an alert in place for when "Rental" is clicked but even that doesn't come up

Comment: @rickyduck would you mind posting your code on jsfiddle.net to I can take a look.

Comment: @PhillPafford lol... I even clicked on his site yesterday... Thanks!

Comment: @rickyduck Made changes to my post. I wouldn't recommend setting the click event on the label and instead set it on the element itself. Jquery-Mobile handles this click event stuff with all the additional content it creates.

Comment: @jostster thanks for your ongoing help... however changing it to the element itself but to no avail... uploaded to the same url.

Comment: @rickyduck can you post your code up to jsfiddle.net so we can modify it for testing.

Comment: @rickyduck ok made changes to my post

Comment: Cheers bro! maybe the 250 bounty was a bit high but oh well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use other events like touchstart along with click. They respond to touch on safari in iOS. This approach worked for me.

```
$('#p_divisionR').live('click touchstart', function(){
    $('#propertyTypeDivision').parent().show();
    $("#propertyType").parent().hide(); 
    $("#propertyTypeDivisionRL").parent().hide(); 
    hideBedrooms();
});
```